# static variable destructor invoked before library destructor

Tags: c++, g++, dynamic-linking, dlopen

consider the following code for a dynamic loaded library built with g++-4.7 on linux, `-fPIC` and linked with `-rdynamic` option:

```
struct Wrapper
{
    libraryUnregisterCbMap_t instance;
    Wrapper() : instance() { HDebugLog("Wrapper CTOR!");}
    ~Wrapper() { HDebugLog("Wrapper DESTRUCTOR!"); }
};
inline libraryUnregisterCbMap_t& getLibraryUnregisterMap()
{
    static Wrapper unregisterLibraryMap;
    HDebugLog("getLibraryUnregisterMap: we have " <<unregisterLibraryMap.instance.size() << " elements. the address of the map is " << &unregisterLibraryMap.instance);
    return unregisterLibraryMap.instance;
}

void registerLibrary(callbackContainer_t* p)
{
  auto& map = getLibraryUnregisterMap();
}

void unregisterLibrary()
{
  auto& map = getLibraryUnregisterMap();
}

void __attribute__ ((constructor)) library_init()
{
  static callbackContainer_t cbContainer;
  HDebugLog("Library constructor: address of static cbContainer is: " << &cbContainer );
  registerLibrary( &cbContainer);
} 
void __attribute__ ((destructor)) library_fini()
{ unregisterLibrary(); }
```

the interesting/annoying part for me is that library_fini() is not being called after i call `lt_dlclose`, so it seems to be rather useless for finalisation, as when i load this module during a run, the destructor of `Wrapper` instance happens **before** the call to `library_fini`. Needless to say, this default behavior does not make any sense.

How do i change this meaningless behaviour? i need to finalise my static data in my library finalization routine. Why `lt_dlclose` is not invoking `library_fini()`?

Answer (score 0):

Let me first admit that I'm out of my depth here. That said, googling turned up a thread that, at least to my limited knowledge, appears to address a similar problem to yours:

http://lists.apple.com/archives/xcode-users/2005/Aug/msg00133.html

Do you happen to be doing whatever you're doing on OSX? There's something in the thread (maybe the second follow-up) about OSX behaving differently, i.e. not calling destructors but just setting memory to be free.

Apologies if the link isn't useful. Just thought I'd have a go since no one else has answered at this point.

## Edit:

Again, out of my depth - but I found two more links that might be relevant:

1. http://phoxis.org/2011/04/27/c-language-constructors-and-destructors-with-gcc/

   - in the comments, people mention having problems with destructors when they use `exit`, and having to use the `atexit` function to overcome these problems
2. http://clang-developers.42468.n3.nabble.com/Priority-settings-for-static-variables-and-attribute-destructor-td4030466.html

   - global resource destructed before **attribute** ((destructor)) function is called. Suggested solution is to use priorities with the destructor.